# Function tf.test.compute_gradient shows unexpected behavior w.r.t the size of the perturbation delta

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, automatic-differentiation

I am trying to use `tf.test.compute_gradient` to check if `tf` can properly differentiate my (rather complicated) custom loss function. However, `tf.test.compute_gradient` shows unexpected behavior w.r.t the size of the perturbation `delta` (`dx` hereafter).

**Theory**

For a 1D function `f(x)`, the numerical Jacobian of `tf.test.compute_gradient` being computed as `(f(x + dx) - f(x - dx)) / (2 dx)`, we expect the numerical jacobian to converge to the true value as `E(dx) = f'''(x) dx^2 / 6 -> 0` with `dx -> 0`. Though I haven't made the calculus for higher dimensions, I expect the behavior to be roughly the same.

**Problem**

However it seems that `E(dx) -> + inf` with `dx -> 0`, even for a very simple function.

If the numerical Jacobian is not converging when it should, how to test the gradients of custom functions, that might have errors in the way `tf` automatically computes the gradient? How to differentiate rounding errors from errors in the automatically computed `tf` gradient? Which value for `delta` should I choose? Does it change with then number of dimension of the problem (*i.e.* if there is a `tf.reduce_sum` and errors accumulate).

**Test**

In the code example below, I made the test for the log of a Normal law. As `f'''(x)` is theoretically null, the numerical jacobian should be exact, yet, `max(Jth - Jnu)` increases as `delta` decreases.

The problem occurs with `dtype=float32` and `dtype=float64`, for any number of dimensions `n`.

Although the error is minimal for `n = 1` and `eval_jac_at = 1`, it reaches non-negligible values for stiffer problems (`eval_jac_at` >> 1) or highly-dimensional problems (`n` >> 1)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.math as tfm
from tensorflow_probability import distributions as tfd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

"""
Comparing theoretical and numerical gradients for a simple function 
using tf.test.compute_gradient as a function of the perturbation delta 

The studied function is the log of multivariate normal law:

log(N(loc, scale)) = \\sum_i (x_i - loc_i)**2 / (2 * scale_i**2) + cst
"""

# number of dimensions
n = 1

# data type
dtype = "float32"

# evaluate jacobian at (in every dimension)
eval_jac_at = 1

loc = tf.cast(0.0, dtype)

# .5 < scale < 1.5 
scale = tf.cast(0.5 + np.random.rand(n), dtype)


norm_dist = tfd.Normal(loc=loc, scale=scale)


def f(x):
    """
    Explicit definition
    """
    return tfm.reduce_sum(-tfm.pow(x - loc, 2) / (2 * scale ** 2))


def g(x):
    """
    Using tfp.distributions
    """
    return tfm.reduce_sum(norm_dist.log_prob(x))


def compute_err_gradient(f, delta):
    """
    Returns max(|Jnu - Jth|) for a function f and perturbation delta.
    Jacobians evaluated at eval_jac_at * [1, ..., 1].
    """
    Jth, Jnu = tf.test.compute_gradient(f, [eval_jac_at * tf.ones(n, dtype)], delta)
    return np.max(np.abs(Jnu[0] - Jth[0]))


# Compute a series of delta = 1 / 2**i
deltas = 1 / np.power(2, np.arange(5, 14))

# Compute error on Jacobian for each value of delta
err_f = np.array([compute_err_gradient(f, delta) for delta in deltas])
err_g = np.array([compute_err_gradient(g, delta) for delta in deltas])

# Print and plot results
print()
print(f"{deltas=}")
print(f"{err_f=}")
print(f"{err_g=}")
print()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.loglog(deltas, err_f, label="f")
ax.loglog(deltas, err_g, label="g")
ax.set_xlabel("delta")
ax.set_ylabel("Jth - Jnu")
ax.legend()
ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
deltas=array([0.03125   , 0.015625  , 0.0078125 , 0.00390625, 0.00195312,
       0.00097656, 0.00048828, 0.00024414, 0.00012207])
err_f=array([1.19209290e-07, 1.19209290e-07, 1.19209290e-07, 1.19209290e-07,
       3.69548798e-06, 3.93390656e-06, 1.91926956e-05, 1.13248825e-05,
       7.23600388e-05], dtype=float32)
err_g=array([1.19209290e-07, 3.69548798e-06, 3.93390656e-06, 3.93390656e-06,
       1.13248825e-05, 1.13248825e-05, 4.97102737e-05, 4.97102737e-05,
       4.97102737e-05], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don’t worry, using `tf.GradientTape` is the most case way to get an auto differential with theoretical value. You can always use `tf.GradientTape` for your training codes. Just like:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow_probability import distributions as tfd
import numpy as np
"""
Comparing theoretical and numerical gradients for a simple function 
using tf.test.compute_gradient as a function of the perturbation delta 

The studied function is the log of multivariate normal law:

log(N(loc, scale)) = \\sum_i (x_i - loc_i)**2 / (2 * scale_i**2) + cst
"""
tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed(0)
# number of dimensions
n = 1

# data type
dtype = "float32"

# evaluate jacobian at (in every dimension)
eval_jac_at = 1

loc = tf.cast(0.0, dtype)

# .5 < scale < 1.5 
scale = tf.cast(0.5 + np.random.rand(n), dtype)

norm_dist = tfd.Normal(loc=loc, scale=scale)

def f(x):
    """
    Explicit definition
    """
    return tf.reduce_sum(-tf.pow(x - loc, 2) / (2 * scale ** 2))

def g(x):
    """
    Using tfp.distributions
    """
    return tf.reduce_sum(norm_dist.log_prob(x))

class MyTest(tf.test.TestCase):
    def test_gradient_of_test_func(self,test_func,inputs,delta):
        theoretical, numerical = tf.test.compute_gradient(test_func,inputs,delta)
        with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
            tape.watch(inputs)
            y = test_func(inputs)
        auto_diff =  (tape.jacobian(y,inputs),)
        # self.assertAllClose(theoretical, numerical)
        tf.print(theoretical)
        tf.print(auto_diff)
        self.assertAllClose(theoretical, auto_diff)
my_test = MyTest()
deltas = tf.convert_to_tensor(1 / np.power(2, np.arange(5, 14)))
for delta in deltas:
    my_test.test_gradient_of_test_func(f,[eval_jac_at * tf.ones(n, dtype)], delta)
print("*"*20)
for delta in deltas:
    my_test.test_gradient_of_test_func(g,[eval_jac_at * tf.ones(n, dtype)], delta)
```

and outputs:

```bash
(array([[-0.9090829]], dtype=float32),)
([[-0.90908289]],)
(array([[-0.9090829]], dtype=float32),)
([[-0.90908289]],)
(array([[-0.9090829]], dtype=float32),)
([[-0.90908289]],)
(array([[-0.9090829]], dtype=float32),)
([[-0.90908289]],)
(array([[-0.9090829]], dtype=float32),)
([[-0.90908289]],)
(array([[-0.9090829]], dtype=float32),)
([[-0.90908289]],)
(array([[-0.9090829]], dtype=float32),)
([[-0.90908289]],)
(array([[-0.9090829]], dtype=float32),)
([[-0.90908289]],)
(array([[-0.9090829]], dtype=float32),)
([[-0.90908289]],)
********************
(array([[-0.9090829]], dtype=float32),)
([[-0.90908289]],)
(array([[-0.9090829]], dtype=float32),)
([[-0.90908289]],)
(array([[-0.9090829]], dtype=float32),)
([[-0.90908289]],)
(array([[-0.9090829]], dtype=float32),)
([[-0.90908289]],)
(array([[-0.9090829]], dtype=float32),)
([[-0.90908289]],)
(array([[-0.9090829]], dtype=float32),)
([[-0.90908289]],)
(array([[-0.9090829]], dtype=float32),)
([[-0.90908289]],)
(array([[-0.9090829]], dtype=float32),)
([[-0.90908289]],)
(array([[-0.9090829]], dtype=float32),)
([[-0.90908289]],)
```

Comment: Aren't theoretical and auto_diff the same thing, as in computed the same way? Would your test detect if there was an error in a `@tf.custom_gradient`?

Comment: Yes, they all base on `pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_TapeGradient()` and only have  some differences that independent of  diff calculation. So they have the same result.  `@tf.custom_gradient` will influence the function's grad both in `tf.test.compute_gradient`'s `theoretical` and `tf.GradientTape`, they still have identical results.

Comment: Then I am afraid that this solution does not solve my problem: I want to detect possible errors in the way the gradient is automatically computed by `tf`, as for example from an incorrect `@tf.custom_gradient`. That's why I need to be confident that the `numerical` jacobian is correct, or that I know what's its level of precision.